# Delimiter Error in visual force

Tags: visualforce, workflow, visualforce-component

I have Apex class:

```
public class myController {
    public string url{
        get {
            if (this.url == null)
                this.url = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
            return this.url; }
        set;
        }

}
```

for this I have Create the Visual force Component

```
<apex:component controller="myController" access="global">
  <p />
  <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}**/?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1**" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}**/?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1**</apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```

when I am trying to add the ?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1 line Manually in Url:

it is showing Error:

**Error: URL line 3, column 157: The reference to entity "isUserEntityOverride" must end with the ';' delimiter 
Error   Error: The reference to entity "isUserEntityOverride" must end with the ';' delimiter.**

**How to Rectify the Error,Please Anyone Guide me for the Answer,How to add that line Manually in the Component**

Comment: try with this `value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1"`

Comment: after trying that value:Error: URL line 3, column 157: The reference to entity "isUserEntityOverride" must end with the ';' delimiter 
Error Error: The reference to entity "isUserEntityOverride" must end with the ';' delimiter.@TusharSharma

Comment: @TusharSharma what i am doing Mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to change `&` to `&amp;` This will solve your problem.

```
<apex:component access="global">
  <p />
  <apex:outputLink id="urlString" value="{!url}/{!$User.Id}?noredirect=1&isUserEntityOverride=1" >{!url}/{!$User.Id}?isUserEntityOverride=1&amp;noredirect=1</apex:outputLink>
</apex:component>
```

When you add & SF Compiler take this as and search for line end statement. If you want to print&sign then you need to htmlencode this as thats why we use `&amp;`

Comment: can you explain the Logic,How you are done@tushar sharma

Comment: @user36188 check my updated answer